# Lost tag editing privileges?

Tags: support, tags, edits, privileges

I attempted to retag a question, and got an alert saying that I needed to edit 6 characters in the body of the question.

I was able to edit tags without editing the question body yesterday.  I made a somewhat substantial number of tag edits yesterday, but none of these should have been questionable and I've received no notifications on my account.

Is this a bug, or did someone yank my tag edit privileges?

Comment: Just 4 more rep and you can edit without approval :D Then you will have no 6 character limit. I upvoted one of your answers, you can try it!

Comment: @Doorknob ha ha.  Thanks.  I'm still curious about what happened, though.

Comment: yeah, I have no idea what happened.

Comment: It seems that [retag question privilege disappeared](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Currently, there is no privileges in the 500 reputation mark. e.g. trivial retag [bothered 5 people](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2477089).