# Is adding/removing tags too minor an edit?

Tags: discussion, tags, review, too-minor

Ive just started doing reviews on stackoverflow, and after reading some of the debates about minor edits here on meta and developing my personal thoughts thoughts on the topic, I wonder about the case for adding tags.

I've seen that adding/removing a single or even a couple of tags is often considered too minor by other reviewers. However, this included at least one occasion when the single added 'java' tag was key which brought the entire question into context.

Unfortunately I havent been able to find that example again.

While I can see how pedantic minor spelling or grammer tweaks can and should be considered too minor, with tags you get more than a slight increase in readability. It helps bring the right people in on the question, helps give context to the question, helps remove confusion when incorrect tags are removed, and depending on the tag type also adds colouring to any code samples.

So is it ok to approve simple tag additions/removals, or should they be considered too minor?

Comment: Tags are just as important as any other edit.  So judge them as you would anything else.  Is the tag edit necessary, and is it the only thing wrong with the post?  If so, then accept.  If not, then reject or improve.

Comment: yup, I knew it was a dup, and copied the wrong post.  Good find on your own

Comment: Editing tags had been a [privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) before, [when did it disappeared](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183720/lost-tag-editing-privileges)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I consider an appropriate tagging a very important feature of a question, as tags play a fundamental role in connecting the right people to the right questions.

In my opinion, it's absolutely ok to approve (appropriate) tag edits and it shouldn't be considered as too minor.

Answer (score 5):

[This cat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/wont) has been doing nothing but editing tags, and leaving many, MANY preferred fixes left unfixed.  Once you hit a certain rep limit you can do them without approval.  Therefore, then answer is that you shouldn't do that until you hit 3K rep.  Then, fire away!

Comment: Question edits don't need approval at 2k, not 3k, just for the record.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I will reject tag edits that leave other problems unfixed (left the "*Thanks in advance*" in? **<kbd>Reject</kbd>**). However, if the post is otherwise well-polished, and the tag edit is appropriate - sure, go right ahead, have my approve vote; you're making the question better.

Comment: Instead of rejecting, wouldn't it be more appropriate to Improve such edits, marking the suggested edit as useful?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Probably, but some days I just can't be bothered fixing the post myself.

Comment: Well you are basically rejecting the suggested edit for being sloppy, so isn't it a bit incoherent? I'd just approve the edit and - if I have time and will - improve it even more. If the edit is increasing the overall quality of the post I'd never reject it.

Comment: If you can't be bothered fixing the post then you should let someone else does it. The post will still be better off with the tag improvement.

Comment: @Gabriele The idea is to avoid large numbers of little edits and preferably have a low number of significant edits (or just 1). Having several different editors on your post can push it into community wiki. If there are 20 spots that can improve, a single edit should cover _most_ of them - they shouldn't all be made in 20 separate edits.

Comment: That is not constructive at all. Punishing someone for not fixing every single mistake should not be tolerated. Every fix is a fix, no matter the size.