# Tag edit rejected as too minor (not suggested edit)

Tags: support, tags, edits

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19733181/752320) and decided it needed a [c](/questions/tagged/c) tag. So, I hit edit and added a `c` to the tag line.

It was rejected as something along the lines of **"This edit is too short to improve it"**. I don't have the exact wording, didn't grab a screenshot. Confused, I tried again, this time adding an edit comment like "added c tag". Same result.

Now, I get that it's a short edit, but it had no language tag, while the OP was clearly asking about c. From what I've seen here on meta, tag edits shouldn't normally be rejected as "too minor".

To be clear, this was **not** a suggested edit, since I have the editing privilege.

To add insult, a minute later another user *suggested* the *same* edit(tag [c](/questions/tagged/c) only) and it was approved.

Why?

Comment: Shouldn't have been a problem, at least not according to [this question posted yesterday][1]. [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203766/is-adding-removing-tags-too-minor-an-edit/203769

Comment: Yea, there are several questions on the topic, all basically saying "approve them". I guess I'm trying to figure out why my **edit** was rejected by the system, where it lets someone **suggest** the same edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The edit was suggested at 18:39 and approved at 18:43 as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3266513):

> [image]      [image]

As far as I can tell from knowing the system for a while (not 100% sure though) this means you clicked the "edit" link before 18:39:10 (otherwise you would have got the review options) and submitted after 18:39:10 thus getting the error, since the system treated this as Improve, even though it was done outside the review system.

Worth to mention that if you would've made different edit it would have passed, kicking out the suggested edit as a side effect. (Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19733265/revisions) for example where LarsTech unintentionally caused auto-reject by editing)

Comment: This could make sense, but the error message definitely threw me for a loop. I thought there was a separate message for "go look at the post again, it might have changed while you were editing".

Comment: @Geobits There is, and you'd have seen that if the edit was approved.  This is the case of you submitting an edit when there was a suggested edit still pending.  Yeah for race conditions.

Comment: Gotcha, just making sure I wasn't crazy, because I swore I'd seen it before.